# How a proof like this should be written?

Tags: soft-question, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm studying with Apostol's Calculus I, and it has required me to carry out some proofs, which I'd never done before (which has turned out to be pretty neat, by the way).

When proving a statement (specially with inequalities) sometimes at the end I get a different thing from what I started off with. Since I was the one who carried out the proof, I was focus enough as to know that that is just fine (provided I didn't make a mistake). But sometimes I've needed to read the proof backwards, in order to make sure it's okey. If I think from a reader's point of view, that could be a bit painful. It looks like writing the proof ''upside down'' would avoid to require from them an special attention along the way.

I would like to exemplify this with the following proof by induction. Alternative A is the inductive step carried out as I would do/write it the first time. Alternative B is almost the same thing but in opposite order.

Trying to be clearer, my questions are:

- Which of them is ''better'': A or B?
- Do I have to write a proof like B whenever possible?
- If at the end of the proof I get something that looks a bit different from the statement to be proved, do I have to write something special that ties the two things together? Or do I have to assume that the reader will have to handle that?

---

**To prove:** $P(n): n^{p+1} < (p+1)\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni^p\qquad \text{For } n\ \text{and }p \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Proof (by Induction):**

**Base Case:** Prove that $P(1)$ is true

$$\begin{align*}1^{p+1} &< (p+1)\sum_{i=1}^1i^p\\
1 &< p+1\end{align*}$$

which is true.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume $P(k)$ is true for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, such that

$$k^{p+1} < (p+1)\sum_{i=1}^ki^p$$

**Inductive Step:** Prove that $P(k+1)$ is true, such that

$$(k+1)^{p+1} < (p+1)\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i^p$$

By the Induction Hypothesis, it is true that

$$\begin{align*}(p+1)(k+1)^p + k^{p+1}  &< (p+1)\sum_{i=1}^ki^p + (p+1)(k+1)^p\\
(p+1)(k+1)^p + k^{p+1}  &< (p+1)\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i^p\end{align*}$$

If we can show that $(k+1)^{p+1}  < (p+1)(k+1)^p + k^{p+1}$, then by transitivity we will have proved that $P(n)$ is true.

### Alternative A

$$(k+1)^{p+1}  < (p+1)(k+1)^p + k^{p+1}$$

Let subtract $k^{p+1}$ from both sides of the above inequality

$$(k+1)^{p+1} - k^{p+1} < (p+1)(k+1)^p$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}[(k+1)-k]\sum_{i=0}^pk^{p-i}(k+1)^i &< \sum_{i=0}^p(k+1)^p\\
\sum_{i=0}^pk^{p-i}(k+1)^i &< \sum_{i=0}^p(k+1)^p\\
k^{p-i}(k+1)^i &< (k+1)^p\\
\frac{k^p}{k^i} &< \frac{(k+1)^p}{(k+1)^i}\qquad \text{where } p\ \text{and }i \in \mathbb{N}, p\neq i.\end{align*}$$

which is true.

### Alternative B

Since $k < k+1$, it follows that

$$\frac{k^p}{k^i} < \frac{(k+1)^p}{(k+1)^i}\qquad \text{where } p\ \text{and }i \in \mathbb{N}, p\neq i.$$

Let multiply both sides by $(k+1)^i$

$$k^{p-i}(k+1)^i < (k+1)^p$$

By taking the sum of both sides we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^pk^{p-i}(k+1)^i < \sum_{i=0}^p(k+1)^p$$

Let multiply the LHS by $1 = (k+1)-k$

$$\begin{align*}[(k+1)-k]\sum_{i=0}^pk^{p-i}(k+1)^i &< \sum_{i=0}^p(k+1)^p\\
\sum_{i=0}^p[k^{p-i}(k+1)^{i+1} - k^{p-(i-1)}(k+1)^i] &< (p+1)(k+1)^p\end{align*}$$

And after applying the telescoping property for sums we get

$$(k+1)^{p+1} - k^{p+1} < (p+1)(k+1)^p$$

Therefore, by transitivity $P(n)$ is true as asserted.

Maybe the proofs have some issues. I'm glad if you could point them out too.

Comment: in A you must notice that each step is invertible

Comment: @ali So if my proof looks like A, at the end of it I must write: Readers must notice that each step is invertible.